# What is the difference between "large" and "massive"?

Tags: word-usage

What is the difference between *large* and *massive*? They both seem the same but when I read this article I stumbled across this:

> Scientists using NASA’s Hubble Space Telescope have discovered that the immense halo of gas enveloping the Andromeda Galaxy (M31), our nearest massive galactic neighbor, is about six times larger and 1,000 times more massive than previously measured.
>
> (source: [astronomy.com](http://www.astronomy.com/news/2015/05/nasas-hubble-finds-giant-halo-around-the-andromeda-galaxy) )

EDIT: To clarify this question, I am asking for the difference between *larger* and *more massive*. How can it be 6 times larger but also 1000 times more massive? Is it talking about size?

Comment: You say "they both seem the same but", and then never follow up on the *but*. What is your but? What is your question about this particular paragraph?

Comment: Thank you for the edit. But now you've answered your own question. If something can be 6 times larger but at the same time 1000 times more massive, then *quite obviously* these words do not mean the same thing. As to what they mean, please consult a dictionary of your choosing. The definitions will be clear on how the words differ from one another. Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Large* refers simply to its physical size. *Massive* refers to an object's mass, which in everyday scenarios corresponds to its weight.

So an object like a collapsed star may be relatively small in size but extremely massive, due to its incredibly high density.

Comment: This is exactly correct, but keep in mind that the difference between large and massive is usually only pertinent in a scientific context. In everyday conversation, it would be perfectly normal to describe a big object as massive regardless of its weight, and only a nitpicking pedant would correct you.

Comment: Not if it is a balloon.

Answer (score 0):

Briefly saying, in geology and related disciplines massive is more appropriate and common.

[Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/massive):

> - Massive : Large and heavy or solid.

Answer (score 0):

Since it says a thousand times massive you could say that it means **exceptionally large** with respect to its ***mass***.

> **[massive](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/massive)** (*adjective*)  2:  exceptionally large

Comment: "Large" and "massive" *can* be synonyms in casual conversation, but also have distinct meanings, especially in a scientific context such as the quote given.  Clearly the synonymous meanings cannot be intended in that quote.